# Img with javascript call not functioning on ipad?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ipad

I'm developing a site for a carpet manufacturing client which has a customizer built in.  The customizer basically let's the user select the carpet, room etc. etc. and supplies a preview of how his/her carpet will look.

Now on 2 sections of the customizer where the user scrolls left and right between room and carpet options I use a left and right arrow images which calls a javascript function to scroll left or right. (example of left arrow code).

```
<img src="images/gall_leftarrow.gif" width="24" height="142" onmousedown="galleryLeft()" onmouseup="galleryReset()" />
```

This works perfectly on pc, but on ipad it doesn't work at all?  What could be the reason?  Is it inside the javascript function? Or does it have to do with the img tag?

Would wrapping a href around it and calling the javascript function from there work?

Also my website doesn't work at all on android :(  Why?

Please help, and thanks for your trouble.

Comment: "onmousedown=galleryLeft()" | You have a mouse on your iPad ??

Comment: maybe because there is no events like these on Android...

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but what should I use instead of onmousedown so that the ipad will recognise it?

Answer (score 2):

Your regular mouse events doesn't map to touch events in an UIWebView the way you think it would. Here, read this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Comment: Thanks man, it seems the answers will be somewhere in there! :)  Much appreciated!